# PDO isn't binding PostgreSQL query

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm using PDO to develop an application with PostgreSQL.
The problem is that the binding functions as `PDOStatement::bindValue` and `PDOStatement::bindParam` aren't working at all.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    try{

        $db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=test;host=localhost", "user", "password");

        $all = '*';
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT :all FROM schema.table");
        $sql->bindValue(':all', $all);

        var_dump($sql->queryString);
        var_dump($sql->execute());

    }

    catch(PDOException $e){
        print $e->getMessage();

    }

?>
```

I just cannot understand the reason `$sql->queryString`'s value still is `SELECT :all FROM schema.table`, as it `var_dump()`'d here.

`PDOStatement::bindParam` does exactly the same thing.

Any tips?

**EDIT**: This query is for debugging purposes only! Please, don't care about the query itself but in the method that isn't binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepared statements don't work like that. You can only bind values, not entities.

As far as your statement is concerned, you're executing the query `SELECT '*' FROM schema.table`, *Not*, `SELECT * FROM schema.table`

If you want variable entities (which implies a design flaw about 80% of the time), you will have to resort to string interpolation (or concatenation -- you get the point).

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I'm using this for debugging purposes. The method should bind it anyway, shouldn't it?

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira It will return the string `*` repeated the number of times that there are rows matched against the query. So yes, it will bind, but it is not what you think it is.

Comment: By the execution of `$sql->execute()`, my code is querying on the database the string `SELECT :all FROM schema.table`. If the query were `SELECT '*' FROM schema.table` or `SELECT * FROM schema.table`, I'd be pretty much happy because it would be working fine.

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira Is that based on examining the response or checking queryString? queryString is only the actual queryString when prepared statements are being emulated. With true prepared statements, the string form of the query never actually exists.

Comment: It's based specially on the response. `$sql->execute()` is returning `false`.

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira Hmm, can you set it so that PDO actually throws exceptions so you can see why it's erroring? (Or you can check `errorCode` or `errorInfo`)

Comment: Oh, it said (in free translation) that the type of the first argument could not be determined. So, I've added the 3rd and 4th arguments of `$sql->bindValue()` and it worked great. What a silly error of mine. Thank you for help. I'll choose your answer as the right one.

Comment: @Corbin PDO's failure to throw exceptions by default seems to cause so much confusion. Very frustrating that it can't be changed because of BC.